# How to handle terraform process crash and avoid the resource leak on retry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

I have a microservice deployed in a docker container to manage and execute terraform commads to create infrastructure on AWS. The terraform template supported is as follows:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}


resource "aws_default_vpc" "default" {
  tags = {
    Name = "Default VPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "se_security_group" {
  name        = "test-sg"
  description = "secure soft edge ports"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.default.id

  tags = {
    Name = "test-sg"
  }
}


resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-*********"
  instance_type = "t3.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "test"
  }
  
   depends_on = [
    aws_security_group.se_security_group,
  ]

}
```

With this system in place, while the terraform process is being executed (creating an EC2 instance),if the docker container crashes, then the state file would not have the entry regarding the EC2 resource being created. On container restart, if the terraform process is restarted on the same state file, it would end up creating a whole new EC2 instance resulting in a resource leak.

1. How is the crash scenario in terraform commonly handled?
2. Is there a way to rollback the previous transaction without the state file having the EC2 entry?

Please help me with this issue. Thanks

Comment: This is generally not handled automatically because it does not happen (often enough). If terraform crashes you need to manually deal with the state file and the created resources, delete the resources or import them into the state.

Comment: It can also crash if terraform is using an auth token to access the state and the token expires halfway through an apply. This has happened to me often enough.

Answer (score 1):

> How is the crash scenario in terraform commonly handled?

It depends when did the crash happened. Some plausible scenarios are:

1. Most likely, your state file will remain locked, as long as your backend supports locking.  In this case nothing will be created after restart, because Terraform wont be able to acquire a lock to the state file, so it will throw an error. We will have to force unlock the state.
2. We managed to unlock the state file/the state file was not locket at all. In this case we can have to following scenarios:

- The state file will have an entry with an identifier for the resource, even if there was a crash will the resource was provisioning. In this case Terraform will refresh the state and will display in the plan if there are any changes to be made. Nevertheless, we should read the plan and decide if we would want to apply or do some manual adjustments first.
- Terraform wont be able to identify a resource which already exists, so it will try to provision it. Again, we should read the state file and decide ourselves what to do. We can either import the already existing resource or terminate it and let Terraform attempt to create it again.

> Is there a way to rollback the previous transaction without the state file having the EC2 entry?

No, there is no way to rollback to the previous transaction. Terraform will attempt to provision whatever it is in the `.tf` files. What we could do is to checkout a previous version of our code from our source control and apply that.

Comment: It was observed that in case of a crash in the experiments, the resource which was being provisioned earlier was not recorded in the state file. On reattempt, the terraform ends up creating the same resource again resulting in 2 resources. For example: Considering that the terraform was creating a EC2 instance during which the crash happened. It was observed that on retriggering terraform command, new EC instance with the same name was creating thus causing 2 instances to be present